# Playing a movie file in Eclipse with the Processing plugin

Tags: eclipse, video, processing

I'm trying to just play a basic video in Processing using Eclipse as an IDE. I am using Mac OSX 10.9.2, JRE 7 and Eclipse and Processing (I downloaded the most recent versions today).

I am having problems getting the initial setup correct. I have placed the mov file in the Data folder.

Here is my code:

```
import processing.video.*;

Movie myMovie;

void setup() {
  size(720, 576);
  myMovie = new Movie(this, "a.mov");
  myMovie.loop();
}

void draw() {
  tint(255, 20);
  image(myMovie, 0, 0);
}

// Called every time a new frame is available to read
void movieEvent(Movie m) {
  m.read();
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at processing.video.Movie.init(Unknown Source)
at processing.video.Movie.<init>(Unknown Source)
at processing.video.Movie.<init>(Unknown Source)
at monkey.setup(monkey.java:28)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:1579)
at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:1503)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Animation Thread"
```

Any help would be very appreciated!!!

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/xGsDgO3) Here is a screenshot of my setup

Answer (score 1):

First get a hold of the video.jar file.

On a mac, with the Processing.app v2.1.1 installed, I found video.jar at /Applications/Processing.app/Contents/Java/modes/java/libraries/video/library/video.jar

Copy it over to your eclipse project, then right click the project, select Build Path > Configure Build Path, select add JARs, add the video.jar.